# Show that $\tau$ forms a topology for $\mathbb{R}$. When $\tau$ is a collection that contains $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ and intervals $(a, \infty)$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and let $\tau$ be a collection that contains $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ and all intervals of the form $(a, \infty)$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\tau$ forms a topology for $\mathbb{R}$.

Clearly $X$ and $\emptyset$ are in $\tau$ so the first condition is satisfied. Now to show that for any collection of subsets $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $\tau$ I have that $$\bigcup_{i}U_i \in \tau$$ can I just note that since they're all of the form $(a, \infty)$ the must be subsets $\mathbb{R}$ for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and thus $\bigcup_{i}U_i \in \tau$? Similar argument would probably work for the intersection here?

Comment: $\bigcup_i(a_i,\infty)=(\inf_i a_i, \infty)$ and $(a,\infty) \cap (b,\infty)=(\max \{a,b\},\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

If the $U_i = (a_i , \infty)$

$$
\bigcup_i U_i = ( \inf  a_i , \infty ) \in \tau
$$

If any of them are $\emptyset$ or $\mathbb{R}$, then either reduce to the above case because the union is not affected or the union is again all of $\mathbb{R}$ respectively.

For intersections, $\sup$ instead and note that it is a finite set taking $\sup$ over.

Comment: Not sure I follow with the sup and inf? I have that $\emptyset \subset (-\infty, \infty), .. , (0, \infty), .., (\infty, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$? So wouldn't the union of $U_i$ be a subset of $\Bbb R$?